# Best way to run multiple Kafka console consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka

I write Kafka consumed messages on a file (backup.log). To do this, I created a service on my CentOS which run `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 --topic test --consumer.config consumer.properties >> /backup/backup.log`

I have two Linux host.

Each Linux host one Kafka consumer and each consumer belong to a consumer group. So I have two consumer group.

This way, If a consumer is down, the other consumer has all the messages as he belongs to another consumer group.

Currently, I have only one topic with four partitions.

**Question**: I have to consume multiples topics. I read that it's recommended to add consumers (parallelize) instead of using only one consumer for too many topics/partitions.

-> What is the best way to achieve this? Duplicate the service which runs `kafka-console-consumer.sh`? Or another way?

Comment: What are you trying to actually do here? As in, what's the requirement driving this approach that you're taking?

Comment: As I explained, I have to consume messages from different topics and write messages to a file without interruption.

Comment: Right - but why? Your file is called `backup.log`, so is this some kind of backup mechanism? Or for another program to read? or something else? The answer then drives the best way to achieve this :)

Comment: Ok I got you ! This is just for backup. We store raw logs in case of investigation needed.

Comment: Maybe you can use a FileStream Sink Connector instead 
It enables you to consume from multiple topics

Comment: By the way, you're not "backing up" the entire log message. You're excluding any headers, timestamps, and keys. If you truly wanted a backup, you would actively copy  off the log segments from the broker. If you want to do this for analysis purposes, then using Kafka Connect with Elasticsearch or Splunk would work best